# Problemas com rotas no laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Estou trabalhando com `group routes` no `laravel 5.2` e estou tendo problema com a parte do create.store  a rota que salva meu objeto.

Meu arquivos estão estruturados da seguinte maneira:

ClienteController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CategoriaRequest;
use App\Categoria;

class CategoriaController extends Controller
{
public function index(){
    $categorias =  Categoria::all();

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $categorias;
    }else{
        return view('Categoria.listCategoria', compact('categorias'));
    }
}

public function create(){
    $categoria = new Categoria();
    return view('Categoria.cadCategoria', compact('categoria'));
}

public function store(CategoriaRequest $resquest){
    dd($resquest);
    $categoria = Categoria::create($resquest->all());

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $categoria;
    }else{
        return view('Categoria.listCategoria', compact('categoria'));
    }
}

public function show(Categoria $categoria){
    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $categoria;
    }else{
        return view('Categoria.showCategoria', compact('categoria'));
    }
}

public function edit(Categoria $categoria){
    return view('Categoria.editCategoria', compact('categoria'));
}

public function update(CategoriaRequest $request, Categoria $categoria){
    $categoria->update($request->all());
    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $categoria;
    }else{
        return view('Categoria.listCategoria');
    }
}

public function destroy(Categoria $categoria){
    $deleted = $categoria->delete();

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return (string) $deleted;
    }else{
        return view('Categoria.listCategoria');
    }
}
}
```

CategoriaRequest.php

```
class CategoriaRequest extends Request
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'NmCategoria' => 'required|min:5',
        'DscCategoria' => 'required|min:5'
    ];
}
}
```

Meu model `Categoria`

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['NmCategoria', 'DscCategoria'];

}
```

E minha rota esta assim:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function (){
  Route::resource('categorias', 'CategoriaController');
});
```

> Meu primeiro problema é quando estou clicando em editar, a minha query fica id, sendo que meu campo está CdCategoria, assim dando erro na query:
>
> > SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categorias` where `id` = 1 limit 1)

O que poderia ser ?

Comment: Posta a parte da view também, não precisa ser tudo, apenas a parte que mostra como o valor esta sendo passado e a rota setá sendo chamada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Laravel assume que o nome da sua chave primaria seja `id` caso seja outra coisa tipo `categoria_id` você precisa especificar isso no model.

```
class Categoria extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['NmCategoria', 'DscCategoria'];
    $primaryKey = 'CdCategoria';
}
```

Isso e mais algumas coisa você pode encontrar na [documentação do eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models)

Comment: e se tiver 2 key ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues não me recordo bem, mas acredito que o laravel não suporta chave primaria composta.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues quando precisar de uma chave composta seria um array no `$primarykey = ['chave1', 'chave2'];` e quando utilizar assim tem que desabilitar o auto_increment assim: `public $incrementing = false;`